# Thread 1 signal SIGBART

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, iboutlet

I did some research on this, but alas, no answer. I have made a code machine that uses ASCII code. There are no errors or warnings. But when I run it I get this error: **Thread 1: signal SIGBART**. I think it has to do with UITextView "coded" but I don't know for sure.
EDIT: The crash occurs when I click the "Encode" button ((IBAction)StartEncodeDecode).

All Output Log below. Can't believe I'm such a noob:

> 2013-08-28 14:00:57.086 Code Machine[2285:11303] -[CMViewController decodeEncode:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7151190
>   2013-08-28 14:00:57.155 Code Machine[2285:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[CMViewController decodeEncode:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7151190'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x1c94012 0x10d1e7e 0x1d1f4bd 0x1c83bbc 0x1c8394e 0x10e5705 0x192c0 0x19258 0xda021 0xda57f 0xd96e8 0x48cef 0x48f02 0x26d4a 0x18698 0x1befdf9 0x1befad0 0x1c09bf5 0x1c09962 0x1c3abb6 0x1c39f44 0x1c39e1b 0x1bee7e3 0x1bee668 0x15ffc 0x1ded 0x1d15)
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
>   (lldb)

End edit.

Code is below:

View Controller.m:

```
#import "CMViewController.h"
#import "CMAEncode.h"

@interface CMViewController ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *toCode;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *coded; //I think the problem is with this text view.
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *onOrOff;

- (IBAction)StartEncodeDecode:(id)sender;




@end


@implementation CMViewController


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range
 replacementText:(NSString *)text
{

    if ([text isEqualToString:@"\n"]) {

        [textView resignFirstResponder];
        // Return FALSE so that the final '\n' character doesn't get added
        return NO;
    }
    // For any other character return TRUE so that the text gets added to the view
    return YES;
}
- (IBAction)StartEncodeDecode:(id)sender {

    NSString *finishedText;
    NSString *toCode = self.toCode.text;
    if (self.onOrOff.on == FALSE) {
        finishedText = [CMAEncode encodeText:toCode];
        self.coded.text = finishedText;
    } else { 
    }
}

@end
```

CMAEncode.m

```
#import "CMAEncode.h"

@implementation CMAEncode : NSObject 

+ (NSString *) encodeText:(NSString *)text {

    NSString *ToEncode = text;
    NSMutableString *Encoded = [NSMutableString string];
    int letter;
    NSUInteger i = 0;

    while (i < ([ToEncode length] - 1)) {
        letter = [ToEncode characterAtIndex:i];
        NSString *toAppend = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d|", letter];
        [Encoded appendString:toAppend];
        i = i + 1;
    }

    return Encoded;




}

@end
```

Here's the class where the error actually occurred. It's call main.m:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "CMAppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([CMAppDelegate class])); //This is where the error occurred.
    }
}
```

Thanks for helping!

Comment: What is linked to `StartEncodeDecode:` `IBAction`? Is it a button or something else?

Comment: Just disconnect all connection and connect again.

Comment: @Rajneesh071 I tried it but no difference.

Comment: Why do you think that the problem is related to `coded`?

Comment: Not really your problem: `ToEncode` is not a good name for a local variable. Better use `toEncode`. The same for 'Encoded'. Better start with a lower case. However, you may well use `text` directly. I don't see a reason for that variable at all.

Comment: @Hermann Klecker I think the problem is related to coded because it was when the code changed coded's text that it would crash.

Comment: Where exactly does the sigabrt occur and how did you find out?

Comment: It happens somewhere in the else clause in the IBAction in the viewcontroller.m. I used a breakpoint to figure this out.

Comment: ***If you have a crash, post the actual crash;  the crash report or backtrace.***

Comment: The else clause in the IBAction is empty... post the whole code if you wanna have real help

Comment: The reason the else clause is empty is because I haven't made code for that part. The program is unfinished. But the else clause shouldn't matter it wasn't called when the problem occurred.  @bbum Sorry, I used the wrong word, I'm a noob. I just had an error not a crash. I put a little more info in the post.

Comment: Provide more information regarding the nature of the crash. Does it happen when you run it or when you tap on a button or some other means... or perhaps a crash log would be helpful. On another note try this > go into your viewcontroller in Interface Builder and right click on the views / textbox & button or what ever you have. & make sure you have 1 to 1 mapping & no more, no less. (e.g. you rename an outlet & manually connect it to IB : this case IB would have 2 pointers 1 to new renamed one & other to previous one which doesnt exist.. -> crash )

Comment: @nsuinteger made sure all mapping was correct it was. I never manual added an outlet, so that wasn't a problem. I included crash log and info, hope you like.

Comment: Check in IB ui elements if you have an action performed IBAction linked with name "decodeEncode" . probably because you have linked it in IB (quick way is to right  click on viewcontroller on IB & it will show everything). It seems you have some action being performed by the name "decodeEncode" but the method is not present in your CMViewController class. On side note If you do have this method implemented can you state where it is located ? 

put this method in your CMViewController.m file & check log

`- (void) decodeEncode:(NSObject *)sender
{
NSLog(@"sending object >> %@", sender);
}`

Comment: @nsuinteger That was it! I had an extra action connected to a button. Put it as an answer and I'll declare it the answer. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check in IB ui elements if you have an action performed IBAction linked with name "`decodeEncode`" . probably because you have linked it in IB (quick way is to right click on viewcontroller on IB & it will show everything). It seems you have some action being performed by the name "decodeEncode" but the method is not present in your CMViewController class. On side note If you do have this method implemented can you state where it is located ? put this method in your `CMViewController.m` file & check log

```
- (void)decodeEncode:(NSObject *)sender 
{

 NSLog(@"sending object >> %@", sender); 

}
```